# Invoking a Go Server from Java Script code involving Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-maps, go

I am making a project for my Distributed Systems Class in Go that demonstrates distributed storage and fault tolerance. The back-end is all in GO - I essentially have 2 major functions Add(Args) and Get(Args) in GO.

My front-end is a Web page with Google Maps. The event handlers on the map would be Javascript functions. I can easily extract information like Center of Map, or map frame bounds from the Google Maps API.

My problem is: I don't know how to "call" the GO function/program in the back-end with information from my JavaScript function. I am very new to Web development, so I apologize if this is painfully obvious.

On googling, the only approach I found is running the GO program as some sort of http server on google app engine. I am unsure about the details though.

I'd be happy if someone gives me some references, or points me in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as ajax communication in general way, from the map to the server with GET/POST method.

There are tons of library though, one of the famous library is jQuery.

---

1) Download jQuery library from official page.
http://jquery.com/

2) Deploy to appengine.

3) Try a simple code:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.post("http://yourapp.appspot.com/test/", {
  message : "helloworld"
}, function(response){
  alert(response);
});
</script>
```

4) You also need your GO script to process POST access for "http://yourapp.appspot.com/test/".
(Sorry I'm not familiar with GO language, yet)

5) Googling keywords "ajax jQuery".

---

I hope this steps help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out AJAX - I didn't know exactly what to google here. I found this on googling: http://marcgrabanski.com/article/jquery-google-maps-tutorial-ajax-php-mysql                                                                       It is almost exactly what I wanted - except that they don't use Go for their server. Once I understand how to configure my Go Script to process POST access, I should be fine, thanks!

Comment: That's all you need to get started handling POST requests: http://play.golang.org/p/9YALnnoLE6. Docs are at http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/. Happy hacking!